# List of default Git (commit) messages

Tags: git

I'm looking for a list of default (commit) messages Git creates. We have a `commit-msg` hook in place that enforces certain patterns in commit messages.

**Problem**

This hook has to be updated frequently. Whenever a user runs a Git command that creates a commit message automatically which our pattern doesn't allow we have to adjust it.

Examples of messages Git creates:

- `Merge branch '<branch-name>' ...` (merging)
- `Revert "<original-commit-message>"` (reverting commits)

Is there a list of messages we should cater for?

Comment: You do know that people can choose to use their own message for things like merges and reverts.  Also, how will you know the difference between a default got message and one entered by a user that uses the same pattern?

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm interested in the Git *defaults*. There's no way the hook can tell wether the message was created by the user or by Git. We accept this is a condition we can't change.